# script to read a file with IP addresses and login

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file named "host.txt" with listing IP addresses of two systems.

```
~] cat hosts.txt
10.1.1.10
10.1.1.20
```

Using below script I am trying to login to each system, check status of a service and print the output of each system. The script prompts to login, however does not continue to execute the /opt/agent.sh status command. Can someone please help fix this script?

```
#!/bin/bash
for HOST in `cat hosts.txt`
do
ssh root@$HOST
STATUS=`/opt/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}'`
echo $STATUS

if [ $STATUS! == "isrunning" ]; then
echo "$host == FAIL"
else
echo "$host == PASS"
fi
```

Comment: Do you have `ssh` keys set up to enable password less ssh? Your `if` condition is incorrect, probably you meant `[ ${STATUS} != "isrunning" ];`

Comment: No ssh keys involved, wanted to login manually and then should continue with check the service status. The if condition was actually a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You script does not continue until the `ssh` command completes, which does not happen the interactive shell on `$HOST` that you started with `ssh` exits. Instead, you want to execute a script *on* `$HOST`.

(Also, note the correct way to iterate over the contents of `hosts.txt`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read HOST; do
do
  if ssh root@$HOST '
      STATUS=`/opt/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}'`
      [ "$STATUS" = "isrunning" ]
   '; then
       echo "$HOST == FAIL"
  else
       echo "$HOST == PASS"
  fi
done < hosts.txt
```

The remote script simply exits with the result of comparing `$STATUS` to "isrunning". An `if` statement on the local host outputs a string based on the that result (which is the result of the `ssh` command itself). This saves the trouble of having to pass the value of `$HOST` to the remote host, simplifying the quoting required for the remote script.

Comment: Would it be simpler to execute only `/opt/agent.sh` on the remote host: `STATUS=\`ssh root@$HOST /opt/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}'\``?

Comment: I tried but getting the following error. BTW I had removed the additional do in second line.  And also, the script gets executed only on the first IP address in hosts.txt file. 
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==1{print
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
bash: line 2: [: !=: unary operator expected

Comment: this is output of agent.sh status. And intention is to just capture "is running" which tells the status.                               #~] /opt/agent.sh status

Agent is running (PID:24037).

Current agent bundle: agent-5.0.0

Server IP address: 10.10.1.100
                                                                                        The awk was to extract is running and print as a result. Is there a better way to capture this?

Comment: If the `awk` command produces no output, `$STATUS` needs to be quoted to prevent an empty string from causing the error you see. I changed the operator back to `=`, since I thought the `$STATUS! ==` in your question was a typo for `$STATUS !=`. Please adjust as necessary for your situation.