# How to ssh into and issue command to list of ip addresses in a txt file Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, openstack

I have a list of ip addresses in a text file that I wish to use in a script.
Here is the code outputting the ip addresses in the text file

`openstack server list | grep agent | awk '{print \$9}' >> ${STACK}_list.txt`

I would like to retrieve the ip addresses and use in a loop by ssh'ing in to them but not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this post.
[script to read a file with IP addresses and login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201911/script-to-read-a-file-with-ip-addresses-and-login)

Might be helpful for you.

Thanks.
Subhadeep

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to filter all ip addresses from the server list-output:

`openstack server list | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*'`

You could pipe this output into a file if you need or to use this within a bash-script you could make something like this, without writing it into a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

ADDRESSES=$(openstack server list | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')

for ADDRESS in $ADDRESSES
do
    echo "ip: $ADDRESS"
done
```

It reads all ip-addresses from ther server-list output and iterate within the for-loop over this output and prints each ip separate on the terminal. Instead of the `echo` you could insert your ssh-command.

Example-server on my deployment:

```
root@m1r1:~# openstack server list
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name                  | Status | Networks                 | Image          | Flavor |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------------+--------+
| 46d04a77-4d33-4bb3-8214-b1444eed33a3 | server1               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.131 | cirros         | XS     |
| e9489aca-00c3-4fc9-afc5-515c08b17406 | server2               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.61  |                | XS     |
| ea8cec6a-a8d5-4bbb-970e-aaf65d7374b2 | server3               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.163 | cirros         | S      |
| 7d934ec4-1d53-467b-9220-d67b4b68a832 | server4               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.184 |                | XS     |
| 74d3036e-372a-4566-8ba2-10a0760c5562 | server5               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.232 | cirros         | XS     |
| e08e1637-f4df-478d-a478-6578d038cb22 | server6               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.190 |                | XS     |
| 8307a481-679e-4df0-a64e-3a497b13ac81 | server7               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.202 |                | XS     |
| 38d10b12-daa5-483e-b9a5-9a16ba14d841 | server8               | ACTIVE | l2-network=192.168.4.250 | cirros         | XS     |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------------+--------+
```

Output of this example:

```
ip: 192.168.4.131
ip: 192.168.4.61
ip: 192.168.4.163
ip: 192.168.4.184
ip: 192.168.4.232
ip: 192.168.4.190
ip: 192.168.4.202
ip: 192.168.4.250
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

openstack server list | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' > stack

while $(wc -l stack | cut -d' ' -f1) -gt 0 ]
do
  ipnumber=$(sed -n '1p' stack)
  echo "${ipnumber}"
  sed -i '1d' stack
done
```

The echo command there is just a placeholder.  You can replace it with ssh, or whatever else you want to do, with the IP number in the variable.